# Add a different random row from table A to each row in Table B

Tags: sql, oracle

I have tow tables the one named A and the second named B,
I want to add a a **different ** random row from table A to each row in Table B.
There are no cummon fields between the tables.

I tried to do:

```
select idA,idB

from A,(select idB

        from B

        Order by dbms_random.random

        fetch first 1 row only)
```

But, the select in the 'from' executed only once. So, I got the same row from table B to all rows in table A.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "different" if there are no common columns/fields?

Comment: Do they have the same number of rows?

Comment: You can use lateral joins to do this. The syntax depends on the specific database. What database are you using?

Comment: Since you don't use UNION, you will not produce another row, but just add further columns to the same row. Did you explain your goal incorrect or is your query incorrect?

Comment: I dont have the same number of rows.
I mean by "diffrent" to:
B contains the days of the week
A contains details about persons 
and I want to add to each person one and diffrent day (Of course, there can be duplicates, meaning that everything will not be the same)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lateral join. Guessing by `dbms_random.random` function you are using the Oracle database.

In Oracle you can do:

```
select A.idA, x.idB
from A,
lateral (
  select idB
  from B
  Order by dbms_random.random + A.idA * 0
  fetch first 1 row only
) x
```

**Note**: For the lateral join to be run for every single row you need to produce a "dependency" from it to the main table. In this case we can trick Oracle by adding `+ A.idA * 0`; this doesn't have any side effect, except that Oracle thinks the lateral row depends on the primary one.

See [running example](https://dbfiddle.uk/RhCrUyfw).

Comment: Yes, there is "lateral" in Oracle.

Comment: I tried, This assigns the same value to each row in A :(

Comment: Fixed. The dependency was added.

Comment: Its genius!! I've been on this for so long. Thanks!!

Comment: Wow, adding "+ A.idA * 0" is quite clever!